# Is there a totally empty Bash file I can use (or create) to extend .bashrc and .profile?

Tags: bash, login, profile, dot-files

I know that by principle, one shouldn't change `.bashrc` and common changes like creating an `alias` should better be done in `.profile` instead.

When I rent a new [IaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_service) system with Bash as main shell, the first step I take is (an extended version) of this:

```
cat <<-EOF >> "$HOME"/.profile

    set -x && complete -r
EOF

source "$HOME"/.profile
```

The extra empty line there between the "routine" to the "subroutine" content is because `.profile` **already includes some data**, and I want to separate the new data I append (which can be more than the single line of `set -x && complete -r`) from the rest of the already-present data.

I need another file, one that comes empty but also acts as a "boot file" similarly to `.bashrc` and `.profile` to which I can append the data without an extra empty line. A quick look in my user's directory in Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) shows no such file.

Is there a file like I desire in another directory or should I create one myself? If so, please only hint how it should be done

Comment: Not an answer, since I'm questioning one of your assumptions. Why do you *not* want to change your (own) .profile or .bashrc?

Comment: Have you researched `/etc/skel`?

Comment: @eyoung100 after you mentioned it. I understand it uses to set the structure of a new user's directory, but I already created my user and doesn't want to create a new one...

Comment: @JeffSchaller First, by principle I'd like to avoid hanging existing shell-direction files as much as I can. Secondly, and as absurd as it can be grasped - I prefer to save this extra line

Comment: @JohnDoea  I'm not saying create another user.  Consider reading the file in: `/etc/skel/.profile`  Create a template etc, `cat` it in then save the result to your `.profile`

Comment: @eyoung100 so the new file will also include some text in it which will must be there (before my own code)? hmm, that's not exactly what I'm looking for, I need a file that could be recognized as extending `.bashrc` and/or `.profile`, likely by its very file name, but will be totally empty of anything besides my own code above (without the single line I mentioned, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that by principle, one shouldn't change .bashrc and common changes like creating an alias should better be done in .profile instead.

This doesn't make any sense. You probably misunderstood what you read. There is no reason why you shouldn't change `.bashrc`. On the contrary, this is *your* customization file. It's there precisely so that *you* can put whatever *you* want in it. You don't have to keep whatever was there at the beginning, and you can add what you want.

`.profile` and `.bashrc` are both your customization files, but they have different roles. `.profile` is for login-time things like environment variables. `.bashrc` is for shell configuration like aliases and completion settings.

`set -x` is for debugging only. `complete -x` is a shell customization, not a login-time setting, so it goes into `.bashrc`.

> I need another file, one that comes empty but also acts as a "boot file" similarly to .bashrc and .profile to which I can append the data

If for some reason you want to keep whatever was there at the beginning but don't want to continually modify the existing files, then you can create other files, and put an instruction in `.profile` and `.bashrc` to include your file. In both `.profile` and `.bashrc`, you can use the command `.` (nicknamed “dot”) followed by a file name to read instructions from that file. For example, if you want to put all your customizations in a directory called `etc` so that you can quickly deploy it, then here's what you can do:

- Login-time things such as environment variables go into `~/etc/profile`.
- Bash customizations go into `~/etc/bashrc`.
- Your first-time deployment code can be something like this.

  ```
  rsync -a remote-deployments/etc mynewhost.example.com/etc
  ssh mynewhost.example.com -c <<'EOF'
  grep -q -s -F '~/etc/profile' ~/.profile || echo '. ~/etc/profile' >>.profile
  grep -q -s -F '~/etc/bashrc' ~/.bashrc || echo '. ~/etc/bashrc' >>.bashrc
  EOF
  ```

> without an extra empty line.

You chose to put an empty line there. It doesn't hurt anything. There is absolutely no reason not to put an empty line. But if you don't want an empty line, it's your choice. Don't put it there.

Comment: +1 Gilles, one small thing, please; `complete -r` seems to work great for me from `.profile`; if I understand you correctly, philosophically it should be in `.bashrc` but there is no prevention to put it in `.profile` as an exception, so it shouldn't hurt, right?

Comment: @JohnDoea If you put it in `.profile`, it'll cause an error if `.profile` is executed by a different shell (which may not matter to you if you only ever log in with SSH) and it won't take effect if you run a non-login shell (e.g. in screen or tmux). It's a practical difference, not a philosophical difference.